# Webpack css loader error when running npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, css-loader

When i run npm start on my project i get an error that says:

> [webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been
> initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API
> schema.
>
> - configuration has an unknown property 'modules'. These properties are valid:    object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?,
>   devServer?, devtool?, entry?, experiments?, externals?,
>   externalsPresets?, externalsType?, ignoreWarnings?,
>   infrastructureLogging?, loader?, mode?, module?, name?, node?,
>   optimization?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?,
>   profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?,
>   resolve?, resolveLoader?, snapshot?, stats?, target?, watch?,
>   watchOptions? }    -> Options object as provided by the user.    For
>   typos: please correct them.    For loader options: webpack >= v2.0.0
>   no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
>   Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
>   Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
>   plugins: [
>   new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
>   // test: /.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
>   options: {
>   modules: …
>   }
>   })
>   ]

I´ve updated webpack (v5) and followed the instructions of webpack v5 doc on css loaders (https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/#thisgetoptionsschema) and my webpack.config.js looks like this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "main.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    modules: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],            
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

**index.js**

```
import {run} from "./app/app";
import "./main.css";
import { AlertService } from "./app/alert.service";
import { ComponentService } from "./app/component.service";
const alertService = new AlertService();
const componentService = new ComponentService();
run(alertService, componentService);
```

**main.css**

```
body{
    background-color: purple;
}
```

**devDependencies**

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.61.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  }
```

Can someone please help me out.

Comment: The property `modules` should be called `module`

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine except one object key.
[According to webpack configuration](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/), your loaders shall be inside rules array, which is key of the **module** object.

In your configuration file, you have *modules* instead of **module**.
Please change that and let me know if it works :)

**Correct config**

```js
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "main.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],            
            },
        ],
    },
};
```